# Having some trouble with returning boolean value from a function

Tags: c#

I'm trying to create a boolean return function that would check the value from the textbox,check it with the datareader from a table to find whether they found a match or not and then return a boolean value.I've been using this function quite sometime now and it works fine.

```
   public Boolean testname()
    {
        Boolean test=false;
        SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=(LocalDB)\v11.0;AttachDbFilename=C:\Users\noewayout\Documents\Project.mdf;Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=30");
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select CNAME from CUSTOMER", conn);
        conn.Open();
        SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
        string cname = "";
        while (dr.Read())
        {

            cname = Convert.ToString(dr["CNAME"]);
            if (cname == textBox1.Text.ToString())
            {
                test = true;
                return test;
            }


        }
        conn.Close();
        return test;
    }
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (textBox1.Text == "")
        { MessageBox.Show("Please type in Customer Name"); }
        else
        {
            Boolean boo = testname();
            if (boo == false)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Invalid Customer Name");
            }
            else if (boo == true)
            {
                try
                {
                    SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=(LocalDB)\v11.0;AttachDbFilename=C:\Users\noewayout\Documents\Project.mdf;Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=30");
                    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select ONAME,PRICE,QTY from OIL_TYPE,SALEOIL,CUSTOMER where OIL_TYPE.OID=SALEOIL.OID and CUSTOMER.CID=SALEOIL.CID and CNAME='" + textBox1.Text.ToString() + "'", conn);
                    conn.Open();
                    SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
                    int qty = 0;
                    int price = 0;
                    string oname = "";
                    while (dr.Read())
                    {
                        oname = Convert.ToString(dr["ONAME"]);
                        qty = Convert.ToInt32(dr["QTY"]);
                        price = Convert.ToInt32(dr["PRICE"]);
                        int tcost = qty * price;
                        MessageBox.Show("Oil Name\t\tQuantity\tPrice\tTotal Cost\n" + oname + " \t" + qty + "\t" + price + "\t" + tcost);
                    }
                    conn.Close();
                }
                catch (SqlException) { MessageBox.Show("Error!!"); }
            }
        }
    }
```

However I'm having trouble with this simple check method for the past few hours.

```
public Boolean testname()
    {
        Boolean test = false;
        SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(dbsource);
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select Fid from Firearm", conn);
        conn.Open();
        SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
        string tfid = "";
        while (dr.Read())
        {

            tfid = Convert.ToString(dr["Fid"]);
            if (tfid == textBox6.Text.ToString())
            {
                test = true;
                return test;
            }


        }
        conn.Close();
        return test;
    }
    private void searchbtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

          string  mysql = "select * from Firearm where Fid= '" + textBox6.Text + "'";

          if (textBox6.Text == "")
          { MessageBox.Show("Please fill the text field"); }
          else
          {
              Boolean boo = testname();
              if (boo == false)
              {
                  MessageBox.Show("Invalid Fid");
              }
              else if (boo == true)
              {
                  try
                  {
                      SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(dbsource);
                      SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(mysql, conn);
                      SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
                      DataTable dt = new DataTable();
                      sda.Fill(dt);
                      dataGridView1.AutoGenerateColumns = true;
                      dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;

                      dataGridView1.Show();
                  }
                  catch (SqlException) { MessageBox.Show("Error!!!"); }
              }
          }
    }
```

It kept returning false even though i entered the correct id value.I've tried everything that i know off but still no go.Any help or suggestion would be great.Thanks

Comment: Is your Fid column datatype `char` or `nchar` instead of `varchar`?

Comment: You do not need to call .ToString() on txtBox.Text property as Text property is already of string type

Comment: @Manish Dalal Yes,Fid is varchar(20) and i've  also tried ditching .ToString() but it is still returning false.

Comment: Put a breakpoint and see if your code is entering the `while(dr.Read())` loop.

Comment: Another thing to check is, are you referring to the same data source `dbsource` because in your first function you are attaching a database to use while in second function you are using `dbsource` variable

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to compare as below

`if (tfid.Trim() == textBox6.Text.Trim())`

Comment: .Thank for the help.You've just ended the hour's long headache of mine.But why would it works with trim but not with normal comparison of mine? And yes ,both tables use different database and CNAME uses "nvarchar" and Fid uses "varchar".Do you think that have something to do with it.